# How to delete tableview row in section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I have a tableview with 2 sections and multiple rows in each. I'm trying to remove a row when a button confirmation is tapped.

Orgininal data looks like this

```
{
  "section one": [
    {},
    {}
  ],
  "section two": [
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

I create an array of sections where each one includes an array of objects. Everything displays correctly just can't get the delete.

In my service:

```
    var items = [Items]()
    var mySections = [MySection]()
```

In my view:

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return myService.mySections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let mySection = myService.mySections[section]
        return mySection.items.count
    }
```

I've been playing around with this as lots of examples show:

```
    myService.mySections[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    followupTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

I cannot seem to target it correctly, I can't simply use the .remove because of the nested data. The remove error is Value of type 'MySection' has no member 'remove'

Comment: It would be really helpful if you show your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` data source methods.

Comment: MySection should be array not only one object

Comment: mySections should be declared like this **var mySections : [[MySection]] =  anyValues**

Comment: Thanks. I've added those 2 functions and more details. The data I have is an array of sections with each containing an array of objects.

Comment: Y not  myService.mySections[indexPath.section].items.remove(at: indexPath.row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the data structures shown in `numberOfRowsInSection`, your code to remove a row needs to be like the following:

```
myService.mySections[indexPath.section].items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
followupTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

But this does require that `items` be a `var` and not a `let`. So you may need to update your data structure to support this.

Also note that you do not want to delete an item from some specific index path and then remove the cell at index path 0, 0. You want to remove from the same index path.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made it a let but I'm getting an immutable error when adding your code. My data is in a separate service class. I'll have to figure out how to update that data before I can run it.

Comment: I just changed the variable to model public instead of private in my class. Not sure if that's a good idea but I couldn't get that .remove function to work in a setter public(set) public var items: Array<Item>

Comment: Yes, you either need to make the `items` setter public or add a public method that you can which in turn updates `items`.

Answer (score 1):

To get your issue to work you must have an array of arrays like this

```
 var mySections = [["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"]]
```

here mySections is `[[String]]` , you can have `[[MySection]]`

Then you will be able to

```
mySections[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
```